# read each line from a file and use it as a variable in curl command

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I have a file called list which has something like

```
1.html
2.html
3.html
```

I want to run a curl command to read each line from the file and use it as a variable for curl, e.g.:

```
curl "xyz.com/v1/{input from each line of file}
```

Please help....

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
xargs -I{} curl "xyz.com/v1/"{} <file
```

For each line in your `file`, this runs `curl "xyz.com/v1/"` followed by the contents of that line.

To illustrate what happens, without downloading anything, we can add an echo command:

```
$ xargs -I{} echo curl "xyz.com/v1/"{} <file
curl xyz.com/v1/1.html
curl xyz.com/v1/2.html
curl xyz.com/v1/3.html
```

Note that I left the base URL, `xyz.com/v1/`, in double-quotes as it was in the question.  That means that it is subject to shell expansions.  If you don't want that (and you likely don't), then use single-quotes:

```
xargs -I{} curl 'xyz.com/v1/'{} <file
```